# Execute different functions in the same time

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm creating an app in ReactNative where I'm going to monitoring BLE services from two external devices. 
In particular I read 4 values ( accelerometer, gyroscopic, magnetometer and pressure) for device.

In this device there is a timestamp that I also monitoring.

My problem is that I can't perform these functions at the same time, therefore the data monitoring is staggered (for example, it reads the acceleration twice, once the magnetometer, acceleration again and then the others ..)

```
async notifications() {
    this.deviceRight(this.device1)
    this.deviceLeft(this.device2)
  }

deviceRight(device1) {
    const service = this.serviceGeneral();

    //TimeStamp device destro
    this.monitorRightTimeStamp = device1.monitorCharacteristicForService(service, this.TimeStamp, (error, characteristic) => {
      if (error) {
        this.error(error.message);
        return;
      }
      const buf = Buffer.from(characteristic.value, "base64");
      this.timeS = [0].map(index => buf.readInt16LE(index))
      console.log("timeStamp", this.timeS)
    })

    //Accelerazione device destro
    this.monitorRightAccelerazione = device1.monitorCharacteristicForService(service, this.Accelerometro, (error, characteristic) => {
      if (error) {
        this.error(error.message);
        return;
      }
      const buf = Buffer.from(characteristic.value, "base64");

//…..
    })

    //Giroscopio device destro
    this.monitorRightGiroscopio = device1.monitorCharacteristicForService(service, this.Giroscopio, (error, characteristic) => {
      if (error) {
        this.error(error.message);
        return;
      }
//….
    })

    //Magnetometro device destro
    this.monitorRightMagnetometro = device1.monitorCharacteristicForService(service, this.Magnetometro, (error, characteristic) => {
      if (error) {
        this.error(error.message);
        return;
      }
//…..
    })

    //Pressione device destro
    this.monitorRightPressure = device1.monitorCharacteristicForService(service, this.Pressure, (error, characteristic) => {
      if (error) {
        this.error(error.message);
        return;
      }
```

this is an example about the right device.

I would find a method to execute all the function together maybe with the same time, how can i do? thank you

Comment: I'm not familiar with the API, but you'd think there would be a way to obtain a larger object that contains all the stats at once, and then you'd just extract the data you need from that one object instance instead of making multiple calls for each stat. This would make the stats more in sync with a particular moment in time.

Comment: I have an object to obtain accelerometer, gyroscopic, magnetometer together but not the pressure.

Comment: I'd wrap the calling of these two separate sets of things into two seperate async function that returns a promise. This way you can call both things *almost* instantly and Promise.All the results. That's the best you can do if the pressure thing is really completely separated (unless there's some other server-side API capable of getting all of them at a moment in time).

Comment: Just a second, I have now regroup the accelerometer, gyroscopic, magnetometer together and the pressure alone, always inside deviceRight(device1). What should I do now? :)